# FB user_photo permission not shown to users though i got it approved from facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I got user_photos permission approved from facebook. But when i added it in my ios app and a user clicks on login button facebook does not show the user_photos permission nor it shows other 10 permissions i got it approved from them. It only shows the basic permissions to user.

But if any of fb app developers or administrators try to login through facebook they can see all permissions and I too can get all the required data for the app. But the general public is not able to see them and hence i do not get their informations.

I am using fb graph api v2.2 and sdk 3.23 for ios. And here is my code for including permissions. Thanks for your time.

```
 if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                @"picture.type(large),email,name,location,first_name,last_name,friends,gender,photos,likes,birthday"
                                                           forKey:@"fields"];



      [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_photos",@"user_location",@"user_hometown",@"user_friends",@"user_likes",@"email",@"user_birthday",@"user_education_history",@"user_work_history"]//,@"public_profile,,@"user_about_me",feed
                                       allowLoginUI:YES

                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                                      FBSessionState state,

                                                      NSError *error)
```

Comment: I would upgrade the SDK, as we're in version 4.6.0 currently. I would also try and do the obvious checks: Is your Facebook Application Live? An easy way to test this is to download the latest SDK, open one of the samples that come included, use your app's bundle id and Facebook App Id, and request the permissions you mention are missing. If this works, then you know it's time to update dat SDK.